# how to pass NSUserDefaults integer to a UInt32 object

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, uint32

I am wondering if it is possible to pass an integer value I am creating in my NSUserDefaults into a UInt32 object?

So far I am creating the NSUserDefaults as below.

```
NSString * yourKey = @"RequestNumber";
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:[defaults integerForKey:yourKey] + 1 forKey:yourKey];
```

and then I am trying to pass the user defaults value into my object as below.. However I am fairly positive I am completely wrong... which is why im here :) any help would be appreciated.

```
UInt32 *requestNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:yourKey];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UInt32` is *not* an object but a scalar type.

```
UInt32 requestNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:yourKey];
```

Comment: ah yes.. I have read that before but forgot.. I'm terrible with remembering types and all of that.. thanks for clearing that up and thankyou for the solution.

Comment: damnit!!! i was close! I keep forgetting UInt32 dose not work with pointers.. I keep doing it out of habbit cause of NSStrings etc etc etc thanks again

Comment: C.Johns. If your question was answered, please mark it as such.